# Problems reproducing Ext.net examples

Tags: ext.net, gridpanel

I am trying to reproduce the GridPanel example(http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/ArrayGrid/Simple/) but I got the following error message:

Type 'Ext.Net.Store' does not have a public property named 'Model'.

Source Error:

```
Line 38:         <Store>
Line 39:             <ext:Store ID="Store1" runat="server">
Line 40:                 <Model> (Here is the problem: Cannot resolve symbol 'Model')
Line 41:                     <ext:Model runat="server">
Line 42:                         <Fields>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't want to link offsite here, but this question was also asked (and answered) on the Ext.NET forums, see http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?17718-Problems-reproducing-Ext-net-examples

Answer (score 0):

This example needs Ext.net 2.0 version may be you have attached a old version 1.2 , 1.3 for your project !